# Prevent duplicate row on jquery append

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this js for appending fields, checking blank fields, and to prevent duplicate values at rows. But it only works for checking blank fields. Does this code have any mismatch at placement or something else? Thanks.

```
   <script>
    count4 = 1;
    function appendCertification(){
        var certification = $('#certification').val(); 
        var skillSector = $('#skillSector').val();
        var issueDate = $('#issueDate').val();
        var expirDdate = $('#expiryDate').val();

        if(cerfication == "" || skillSector == "" || issueDate == "" || expiryDate == "") {
             alert("please fill minimum 1 row");
             return false;
         }
         for (var i = 0, row; row = document.getElementById("#certificationTable").rows[i]; i++) {
            var fields = new Array();
            for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
                fields[j] = col.innerHTML;
            }
            if(certification == fields[0] && skillSector == fields[1] && issuedate == fields[2] && expireddate == fields[3]) {
                alert("Duplicate row");
                return false;
                }
         }
        var field = "<tr><td>"+certification+"</td><td>"+skillSector+"</td><td>"+issueDate+"</td><td>"+expiryDate+"</td><input type='hidden' name='certificationVal[]' value='"+certification+"'><input type='hidden' name='sectorSkillVal[]' value='"+sectorSkill+"'><input type='hidden' name='issueDateVal[]' value='"+issueDate+"'><input type='hidden' name='expiryDateVal[]' value='"+expiryDate+"'></tr>";
        $("#certificationTable tbody").append(field);
        count++;
    };

    function clearform(){
        $("#certificationTable tbody").html("");
    };
  </script>
```

Comment: Possible mistyping `issuedate` instead of `issueDate` in `if(certification == fields[0] && ...` on your question and also `expireddate`? Or is it also in your real code?

Comment: We don't know about your page, html part.

Comment: it's all about mistyping, check this http://jsfiddle.net/6Zx5V/ i don't like to -1 your question, but you should check your code with more accuracy

Comment: Hello, html use input text and select option, trigger use onclick at button @Kuzgun,

Comment: yes may just ignore the code, because the actual variable is not in english @user3280126

Comment: have you checked my fiddle? jsfiddle.net/6Zx5V it works!! not only the mistyping of the variables, but also the getelementbyid with the # in the id.

Comment: Ah ya, just checked it, thanks mate @Crisim Il Numenoreano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not considering the mistyping of the variable names, `document.getElementById` use the id of the element without the `#`

so the error is in this row

```
for (var i = 0, row; row = document.getElementById("#certificationTable").rows[i]; i++) {
```

it should be

```
for (var i = 0, row; row = document.getElementById("certificationTable").rows[i]; i++) {
```